# Discord.py - Splitting Output into multiple messages or Embeds

Tags: python, discord.py

Right now I have a shell command that can execute commands on my AWS instance. The only problem is that sometimes the output is too large to show in an embed, is there a way I could split the content so it appears in multiple embeds or using reactions show different parts of the output?

````py
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Bot Manager')
async def shell(ctx, * , command):
    author = ctx.message.author
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    output = ""
    p = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, text=True, capture_output=True, check=True)
    output += p.stdout
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "Shell Process", description = f"Shell Process started by {author.mention}", color = 0x4c594b)
    embed.add_field(name = "Output", value = f"```bash\n{output}\n```")
    timestamp = datetime.now()
    embed.set_footer(text=guild.name + " | Date: " + str(timestamp.strftime(r"%x")))
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)
````

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The embed as a whole can only have a maximum of 6,000 characters, and that is as follows (excluding the title and field names):

- Maximum of 25 fields
- 1024 chars per field value
- 2048 chars in the main description

In your case, you seem to only be using the fields, so that's the one case we need to worry about.

This being said, you can splice up the `output` string accordingly and add fields:

```
num_of_fields = len(output)//1024 + 1
for i in range(num_of_fields):
    embed.add_field(name="Output" if i == 0 else "\u200b",  # You can't have an empty name
                    value=output[i*1024:i+1*1024])
```

The `\u200b` I added was so that you don't get `Output` as the field's name for each new field that gets added. Unfortunately names can't be left blank, so `\u200b` is commonly used as a placeholder. It's unicode for a zero-width space.

---

### References:

- [Embed character limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-limits)
- [`Embed.add_field()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.add_field)